# Why does automapper not handle nested objects without .ForMember?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

The class Person contains many nested objects. When I try to use automapper to map this "Person"-class to a PersonDTO it will not map the values of the nested objects if I dont specify each property like this:

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Mobilenumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContactInfo.Mobilenumber))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Companyname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.Companyname)).ReverseMap();
```

Should Automapper not sense this from just the mapping like below and flatten the object?

```
CreateMap<ContactInfo, ContactInfoDto>().ReverseMap();
```

---

```
public class Person : EntityBase
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.CreationTimeUTC  = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.UpdateTimeUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    public int PersonId {get; private set;}
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreationTimeUTC { get; private set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTimeUTC { get; set; }

    //ContactGroup many-many
    public ICollection<ContactGroup> ContactGroups { get; } = new List<ContactGroup>();

    //Contact-FK
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo {get; set;}

    //Company-FK
    public int CompanyId {get; set;}
    public Company Company {get; set;}


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Firstname + " " + Lastname;
    }
 }

public class ContactInfo : EntityBase
{
    public ContactInfo()
    {
        this.CreationTimeUTC  = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.UpdateTimeUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    public int ContactInfoId {get; private set;}
    public DateTime CreationTimeUTC { get; private set; }

    public DateTime UpdateTimeUTC { get; set; }
    public string Mobilenumber { get; set; }

    //Person-FK
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public Person Person {get; set;}


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Mobilenumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it? You certainly could implement it such that it did so but then you have to consider how many levels deep to go, what to do if multiple options are found, what to do if you don't want to map from child objects, etc. You're doing what many people do and assuming that something should happen because it's convenient in one particular scenario. It's not as generally convenient as you might think.

Comment: What's [built-in](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) and what's [possible](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7).

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper does support automatic projection, but you have to actually follow the conventions to make use of that. Specifically, it requires that the destination property name must be named after the path to the appropriate property in the source. In other words, to auto-map `ContactInfo.MobileNumber` you'd need a property on your destination named `ContactInfoMobileNumber`. Since all you have is `MobileNumber`, AutoMapper doesn't have enough info to determine that it should project the value of from `ContactInfo` there.